# Указание типа переменной в python?

Tags: python, функции, типы-данных

Недавно обнаружил, что в питоне можно делать следующие вещи:

```
def function(a: float, b: pandas.DataFrame):
    pass
```

Объясните, имеет ли вообще смысл указывать тип аргументов? Единственный плюс (даже не питона, а среды), который я нашел, это то, что `PyCharm` при указании типа аргумента будет знать тип переменной и будет предлагать методы этого класса при написании `variable.`

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#use-cases

Comment: Подробнее можно прочитать здесь: [PEP 3107 -- Function Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Указания типов могут быть полезны не только для IDE или линтеров, но и для самого разработчика, особенно, если он начинающий. Немудрено запутаться в коде и переменных, если код не очень ловко написан и типы явно не указаны. Для начала можете указывать, а потом можете от этого и отказаться.

Answer (score 3):

На сегодняшний день аннотации переменных полезны только для IDE и линтеров. Впрочем, на мой взгляд, и эта полезность сомнительна.

Comment: Эээээ, полезность линтеров сомнительна??

Comment: @andreymal полезность аннотаций сомнительна.

Comment: Аннотации упрощают линтерам анализ и обнаружение ошибок, значит сомнительность полезности аннотаций сомнительна, я чего-то не понимаю?)

Comment: Это не _питонично_ :) Я склонен считать, что в динамическом языке следует иначе строить правильный код, так чтобы необходимости проверять типы просто не возникало.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, и вообще лучше писать код сразу без ошибок, ага.

Answer (score 1):

Указание типов как минимум позволяет раньше обнаружить ошибки.

Допустим у вас в функции есть несколько ветвей. Одна из них выполняется редко, но для успешного выполнения требуется строгое соответствие типа. В других ветвях происходит автоматическое преобразование и функция молча выполняет свою работу (не зависимо от соответствия этого преобразования вашим идеям). В этом случае при указании типов ошибка может проявиться еще на этапе трансляции

Comment: насколько я знаю, Python не будет делать проверку типов даже в этом случае...