# Перебор ключ-значение в 2-х и более словарях и запись совпадения в новый словарь через *args

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, словари

Имеется два словаря, нужно перебрать ключ-значение в обоих словарях.
Сравнить если одинаковые ключ-значения с помощью цикла for и параметра *args. Добавить в новый словарь одинаковые найденные ключ-значения.

```
operator_one = { 2: 'break',
         1: 'pass',
         3: 'print',
         4: 'yield',
         5 :'try' ,
         }


operator_two = { 1: 'pass',
         2:'global',
         3: 'yield',
         4: 'print',
         5: 'try',
         }

def operator_important(farg, *args):
    """Перебор ключ-значения в двух словарях при помощи args и записи в новый словарь."""
    operator_main = dict()             # создание словаря и запись в перем
    print("vocabulary_one:", farg)     # вывод первого аргумента
    for key, value in args:            # перебор ключ-значение в обоих словарях
        print("vocabulary_two:", arg)  # вывод второго аргумента
        if key in args and value == args[key]: # если ключ-значение равно аргументу ключ-значение, то создаем новый словарь с ключом и значение
            operator_main[key] = value # добавляем в нов. словарь найденное  ключ-значение, которое совпало
```

Ошибка:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: А как Вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию? Можно глянуть? Тоесть, что по Вашей задумке должно передаваться в список `*args`?

Comment: a = operator_important(operator_one, operator_two) print(a) По задумке сравнение 2-х словарей.

Comment: У Вас изначально подход, ИМХО, не верный. Зачем Вам нужна переменная  `farg` если Вы используете `*args` по сути возвращаяющей кортеж неограниченного количества аргументов. Полагаю, что целью задачи является как-раз создание функции способной сравнить не 2 словаря а энное количество словарей

Comment: Изначально сравнение два словаря, но словарей может быть больше для сравнения.

Comment: Именно это я и имел ввиду, поэтому и обратил на это Ваше внимание. Там у Вас уже как минимум 2 решения в ответах есть. Если нужны будут пояснения, пишите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня вот так получилось:

```
operator_one = {2: 'break',
                1: 'pass',
                3: 'print',
                4: 'yield',
                5: 'try',
                }

operator_two = {1: 'pass',
                2: 'global',
                3: 'yield',
                4: 'print',
                5: 'try',
                }

operator_three = {1: 'pass',
                  2: 'global',
                  3: 'yield',
                  4: 'print',
                  5: 'try',
                  }


def operator_important(*args: dict):
    operator_main = dict()  # Создаем пустой словарь
    for key, value in args[0].items():  # Для ключа и значения из первого словаря...
        check = True  # Устанавливаем флаг проверки в значение "Истина"
        for i in range(1, len(args)):  # Проверяем все словари на совпадение
            if key not in args[i] or value != args[i][key]:  # Если ключ отсутствует в другом словаре 
                                                                        # или его значение отлично от проверяемого
                check = False  # Устанавливаем флаг в значение "Ложь"
                break  # И прерываем проверку ключа
        if check:   # Если флаг сохранил значение "Истина" (То есть ключ присутствует во всех проверяемых словарях
                    # и значения ключа во всех словарях равны
            operator_main[key] = value  # Добавляем ключ и значение в новый словарь
    return operator_main


print(operator_important(operator_one, operator_two, operator_three))
```

#### Немного упростил функцию:

```
def operator_important(*args: dict):
    operator_main = dict()  # Создаем пустой словарь
    for key, value in args[0].items():  # Для ключа и значения из первого словаря...
        for i in range(1, len(args)):  # Проверяем все словари на совпадение
            if key not in args[i] or value != args[i][key]:     # Если ключ отсутствует в другом словаре
                                                                # или его значение отлично от проверяемого
                break  # Прерываем проверку ключа
        else:   # Если цикл не прерывался (То есть ключ присутствует во всех проверяемых словарях
                # и значения ключа во всех словарях равны
            operator_main[key] = value  # Добавляем ключ и значение в новый словарь
    return operator_main
```

Comment: def operator_important(*args: dict)  - зачем dict тут писать? и двоеточие

Comment: это указывает какой тип данных должен быть у аргумента функции. Это не обязательно писать, но при использовании в коде спустя какое-то время после написания функции помогает. К тому-же некоторые IDE подсвечивают аргументы при попытке использовать другой тип данных

Comment: for i in range(1, len(args)) почему мы тут начинаем с 1, а не с 0 ?

Comment: Потому, что сравнивать первый словарь имеющий индекс 0 с самим собой бессмысленно

Comment: @ДенисЛатыпов, по поводу Вашего вопроса относительно указания типа данных для функции, очень не плохо написано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775151/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-python)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете послать параметры в функцию с помощью распаковки, привожу возможные варианты для это функции:

```
operator_one = { 2: 'break',
         1: 'pass',
         3: 'print',
         4: 'yield',
         5 :'try' ,
         }
operator_two = { 1: 'pass',
         2:'global',
         3: 'yield',
         4: 'print',
         5: 'try',
         }
def my_dict(d1, d2):
    d3 = dict()
    for k in d1:
        if k in d2 and d1[k] == d2[k]:
            d3[k] = d1[k]
    return d3

print (my_dict(*(operator_one, operator_two)))
print (my_dict(operator_one, *(operator_two, )))
print (my_dict(operator_one, operator_two, *()))

# {1: 'pass', 5: 'try'}
```

Если вы хотите посылать неограниченное количество словарей в функцию то можно так:

```
operator_three = { 1: 'qwerty',
         2:'global',
         3: 'yield',
         4: 'print',
         5: 'try',
         }
def my_dict(*d_tuple):
    w = [x.items() for x in d_tuple]
    first = w[0]
    other = w[1:]
    res = []
    for f in first:
        s = 1
        for elem in other:
            if f not in elem:
                s = 0
                break
        if s:
            res.append(f)
    return dict(res)

print (my_dict(*(operator_one, operator_two, operator_three)))
# {5: 'try'}
```

Comment: Это не будет работать в случае если словарей будет больше 2х

Comment: а нужно чтобы работало? вопроса такого нет вроде

Comment: Полагаю, что наличие в задании *args подразумевает энное количество словарей, хотя в прямую это не указано

Comment: @Andrey по вашему совету добавил в ответ про неограниченное количество словарей

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в комманде

```
for key, value in args:            # перебор ключ-значение в обоих словарях
```

так как `args` - **кортеж** из одного элемента (словаря, заданного как параметр).

И так, вместо `args` нужно везде писать `args[0]` (и в цикле `for` добавить ещё `.items()`):

```
for key, value in args[0].items():            # перебор ключ-значение в обоих словарях
    print("vocabulary_two:", args[0])         # вывод второго аргумента
    if key in args and value == args[0][key]: # если ключ-значение равно аргументу ключ-значение, то создаем новый словарь с ключом и значение
```

---

Но луже вашу функцию слишком изменить - исключить параметр `farg`, т.к *оба параметра могут быть в кортежи `args`:*

```
def operator_important(*args):
    """Перебор ключ-значения в двух словарях при помощи args и записи в новый словарь."""
    operator_main = dict()                      # создание словаря и запись в перем
    print("vocabulary_one:", args[0])           # вывод первого аргумента
    for key, value in  args[0].items():         # перебор ключ-значение в обоих словарях
        print("vocabulary_two:", args[1])       # вывод второго аргумента
        if key in args and value == args[key]:  # если ключ-значение равно аргументу ключ-значение, то создаем новый словарь с ключом и значение
            operator_main[key] = value          # добавляем в нов. словарь найденное  ключ-значение, которое совпало
```

Comment: Не понятно, выводит у Вас 6 словарей, а надо один новый с новыми ключ-значение найденными в словарях для сравнения, она работает да.